# how to combine two columns to one column like a map in hive?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, hive, hiveql

In hive I have two columns in a table:

```
user_id    product_id    score
1          1, 2, 3       0.7, 0.2, 0.1
2          2, 3, 1       0.5, 0.25, 0.25
```

The type of product_id and score are both string. Now I wish to generate a new column which is combined by product_id and score like this:

```
user_id    product_score
1          1:0.7, 2:0.2, 3:0.1
2          2:0.5, 3:0.25, 1:0.25
```

In the new table, the column product_score is like a map, the product_id is the key and the score is the value, but it is actually still a string. The product_id and score is connected by ':'.  The different product_ids are connected by ',' and oredered by the initial order in product_id in initial table. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use split() to get arrays, map() to convert to map

```
select user_id, 
       map(product_id[0], score[0],
           product_id[1], score[1], 
           product_id[2], score[2]
       ) as product_score

(
select user_id, split(product_id,',') as product_id, split(score,',') as score
  from ...
)s;
```

Comment: I'd use `map(product_id[0], score[0] ...)` here instead of constructing/deconstructing strings

Answer (score 0):

**Solved - merge two arrays columns like key and value map with order**.

**Approach - Explode array with posexplode method and get equal pos value from multiple columns**

SQL Query -

```
with rowidcol as 
(
   select user_id, split(product_id, ',') prod_arr, split(score, ',') score_arr, row_number() over() as row_id 
   from prod 
),
coltorows as 
(
   select row_id, user_id, prod_arr[prd_index] product, score_arr[score_index] score, prd_index, score_index 
   from rowidcol 
      LATERAL view posexplode(prod_arr) ptable as prd_index, pdid 
      LATERAL view posexplode(score_arr) prtable as score_index, sid 
),
colselect as 
(
   select row_id, user_id, collect_list(concat(product, ':', score)) product_score 
   from coltorows 
   where prd_index = score_index 
   group by row_id, user_id 
)
select user_id, concat_ws(',', product_score) as prodcut_score 
from colselect 
order by user_id;
```

Input -
Table Name - Prod -

```
user_id  product_id    score     
1         A,B,C,D      10,20,30,40       
2         X,Y,Z        1,2,3         
3         K,F,G        100,200,300
```

Output -

```
user_id   prodcut_score    
1         A:10,B:20,C:30,D:40     
2         X:1,Y:2,Z:3        
3         K:100,F:200,G:300
```